# Does Google Firestore and/or their Realtime DB have the querying capability to get posts by location (within x miles), order by date, and limit?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I am currently using Firestore for my iOS app and I need to implement a scalable solution for my posts feed. I need to get posts within say 20 miles, order them by date, and limit the amount of posts fetched for pagination. Any and all database solutions would very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Uber open-sourced its geospatial library called H3 (https://github.com/uber/h3) which is absolutely spectacular for geospatial indexing and geoquerying. It's no wonder why they use it for their own geoquerying. It's written in C which is easily interoperable with Swift and it's magnitudes superior to geohashes which IMO are terribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those databases have native geospatial querying capabilities. You would have to use some sort of add-on library to help with that. Geofire and Geofirestore are popular for this.

Comment: Thank you for the timely response! In regard to GeoFire and GeoFirestore, would I still be able to order by date and limit? I'm under the impression that range filters and orderBy must be on the same field and thus those solutions would not be sufficient for my query. Let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: I doubt it, but you can always impose an order on the client app by sorting the results again locally.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! Is combining Firestore with a Cloud SQL instance (connecting through cloud functions) a good / feasible option? That way I could store posts in the SQL database (PostgreSQL/PostGIS) and query it using an HTTPS trigger in my cloud functions? This would allow me to execute much more complex compound queries, right? Just throwing out ideas. Let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  If you're looking to discuss ideas ideas in general, I suggest posting to a discussion forum rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Gotcha. Will do. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

As a low budget/time alternative to libraries, we have implemented storing the first few digits of lat/long coordinates as a document or collection name and then accessed data that way. The first decimal place gives resolution to around 10 miles or so (exact values for longitude change depending on what latitude you are at). So in your database you could have a collection or document named something like `+33.6-112.0`. This would mark a reference in Firestore to put all data within (33.8 N, 112.0 W). Be careful with how you round the exact location data before placing it in the respective document or collection.

Then you can retrieve all data at any location you want. This may not give you exactly 20 miles, but some client side sorting can handle that. Note you could make the reference go to any decimal place necessary to achieve the level of precision you are looking for to minimize data base calls (to save you money) and minimize impact on the user's cell data plan.

This is a rather simple solution with limitations, maybe for an MVP, and if not careful could pull way more data than anticipated.

Below is a chart showing the approximate physical distance between each decimal place **at the equator**. So for example, the distance between (33.3 N, 0 W) and (33.5 N, 0 W) would be about 14 miles.

[image: Distance of each decimal place at the equator]